# Regex to select groups between dots without brackets

Tags: java, regex

I got Strings like this:

```
test.as123[13].tdfv
Parent.child1
test.d12[0].asdf
```

I need a regex which gets me groups like this:

- test, as123, tdfv
- Parent, child1
- test, d12, asdf

So I need to divide the groups on the dot and also remove the brackets in its name.

I tried using negation like this:

```
([^\W\d]+)
```

But there will be child as result and not child1.

My problem is that I'm not sure on how to ignore the specific String `\[\d\]` and keep on matching `\d`

I tried using negative lookahead, but I think I'm doing something wrong.
Here's my attemp:

```
\w+(?!\[[0-9]*?\])
```

This does match for example:

- test, 13, tdfv

Comment: Remove all occurrences of `\[\d+]` and split on `.`. What is the language?

Comment: In which context are you using this? With `python` or `grep` or something completely different?

Comment: @toydarian I'm using it in Java.

Comment: So, `s.replaceAll("\\[\\d+]", "").split("\\.")`? Or `.split("(?:\\[\\d+])?\\.", "")`. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/CQUCp4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did and got this one: ([^\W\.]+)    This still includes numbers inside the brackets.

Comment: Match the square brackets with the digits and capture the word characters in group 1 `\[\d+\]|(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/Lebi1E/1 See https://ideone.com/yVTgpv

Comment: See https://ideone.com/CQUCp4. Without seeing your code, it is hard to suggest the most suitable solution for you. Maybe `.split("(?:\\[\\d+])?\\.", "")` will be even better?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does the trick. Thanks. Can you add it as a answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all occurrences of digits inside square brackets and then split on a dot:

```
.replaceAll("\\[\\d+]", "").split("\\.")
```

Or, you may directly split on the `(?:\[\d+])?\.` pattern:

```
.split("(?:\\[\\d+])?\\.")
```

It matches

- `(?:\[\d+])?` - an optional occurrence of a `[`, 1+ digits, `]`
- `\.` - a dot.

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/CQUCp4):

```
String s = "test.as123[13].tdfv";
String results[] = s.replaceAll("\\[\\d+]", "").split("\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
// => [test, as123, tdfv]

String results2[] = s.split("(?:\\[\\d+])?\\.");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results2));
// => [test, as123, tdfv]
```